# PHP store data from form into MySql DB

Tags: php, mysql, form

This is the first time I've tried this. I'd like some feedback on how I did, including any bad practice warnings. For example is it a really bad idea to allow the code to recreate the table if it doesn't "think" it exists? Would it be better to simply create the table once in a different file?

```
<?php

/*
Database and mail functionality
*/

// get user credentials
$config = parse_ini_file('../config.ini'); // path may vary depending on setup

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', $config['username'], $config['password'],$config['dbname']);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error){
    die('Connection failed. ' . $conn->connect_error);
}

// if table not made yet, create it
if(!$conn->query ("DESCRIBE visitors")) {
    // sql to create table
    $sql = 'CREATE TABLE visitors(
        id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
        email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
        message VARCHAR(500),
        reg_date TIMESTAMP
    )';

    if (!$conn->query($sql)){
        die ('Sorry there was an error. Please try again later.');
    }

}

//insert data into table
//clean data for SQL query
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $data['name']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $data['email']);
$message = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $data['message']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO visitors (name, email, message)
    VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$message')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    $usrMsg = 'Thank you we\'ll be in touch when we have some news';
} else {
    die ("Sorry, there was an Error. Please try again later.");
}

// close connection
$conn->close();

// email
// addresses and default subject
$to = ''; // add details
$from = ''; // add details
$subject = 'New form entry on website';

// prepare message variables - !not sure how to make quotes etc. display properly in email body
$message = wordwrap($data['message']);
$body = <<<_END
Name: {$data['name']}
Email: {$data['email']}
Message: $message
_END;

// send
mail($to, $subject, $body, $from);

?>
```

Comment: Good practice to use `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` as opposed to a simple `CREATE TABLE`, since the former will only issue a warning on a duplicate table creation, while the latter will return an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, as you mentioned, you are pretty new to this, i will start with some novice level advice:

You should refactor your code into seperated functions, both in order to seperate functionality with different purpose, and to be able to reuse.

```
function connect_db($config) 
{
// Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli('localhost', $config['username'], $config['password'],$config['dbname']);

    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error){
        die('Connection failed. ' . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    return $conn;

}

function prepare_visitors_table($conn) 
{

    // if table not made yet, create it
    if(!$conn->query ("DESCRIBE visitors")) {
        // sql to create table
        $sql = 'CREATE TABLE visitors(
            id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
            name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
            email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
            message VARCHAR(500),
            reg_date TIMESTAMP
        )';

        if (!$conn->query($sql)){
            die ('Sorry there was an error. Please try again later.');
        }

    }

}

function save_visitor($conn, $name, $email, $message)
{

    //insert data into table
    //clean data for SQL query
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $name);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $email);
    $message = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $message);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO visitors (name, email, message)
        VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$message')";
    return $conn->query($sql) ;
}

function send_visitor_notification($name, $email, $message)
{


    // email
    // addresses and default subject
    $to = ''; // add details
    $from = ''; // add details
    $subject = 'New form entry on website';

    // prepare message variables - !not sure how to make quotes etc. display properly in email body
    $message = wordwrap($message);
    $body = <<<_END
    Name: {$name}
    Email: {$name}
    Message: $message
    _END;

    // send
    mail($to, $subject, $body, $from);

}

$config = parse_ini_file('../config.ini'); // path may vary depending on setup

$conn = connect_db($config);

prepare_visitors_table($conn);
if (save_visitor($conn, $data['name'], $data['email'], $data['message'])) {
        $usrMsg = 'Thank you we\'ll be in touch when we have some news';
    } else {
        die ("Sorry, there was an Error. Please try again later.");
    }
send_visitor_notification($data['name'], $data['email'], $data['message']);


$conn->close();
```